# UPnP dynamic port forwarding error with UPnP wizard

Tags: upnp

I am using UPnP wizard to try to dynamically open ports, but I can't. I enabled UPnP in my router options.

I'm using UPnP wizard that I downloaded from this link:
[UPnP wizard](https://upnp-wizard.software.informer.com/2.0/)

I downloaded this to check if UPnP works for me, because I wanted to use it for a project where I need dynamic port forwarding

This is the error it shows when I open UPnP wizard:
[error when opening UPnP wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHgmn.png)

Then, when I try to add a rule like this:
[adding port rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuJKS.png)

I get this error:
[adding port rule error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLvit.png)

Does the error mean I can't use UPnP with my router? Or is there something I need to do to make it work and there's still hope? Maybe a range or ports I have to use? If UPnP doesn't work on my router, are there other solutions for dynamic port forwarding that might work, even if UPnP doesn't?

Thanks.